# Different menu displayed on different page

Tags: wordpress, templates, menu

I am trying to build a wordpress theme from scratch. I would like to rebuild this theme: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/pj-life-business-coaching-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/15731863

As you can see here, the navigation is displayed on the right side on the startpage but on different sites it just looks like a normal header. My question here: how can this be done? how can I display a different navigation on a the startpage? is this made by creating a different page template or how can I do this?

I would like to do the same.

kind regards :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using **is_page()** function easily in your wordpress theme. **is_page()** function return boolean that verifies wheather it is expected page or not. You can take further decision according to this return.

example code

```
if(is_page('home')){
//take decision
}else{
//take decsion
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the fast reply! But is 'home' the name of the page or where do I define the name of the parameter?

Comment: and where do I have to put in the "is_page" function to display a different menu?

is iit something like:

if(is_page('home')){
<nav-menu class="start">....</nav>}

else{
<nav class="standardnav">....</nav>
}


?